# Specifying axis scaling

Tags: tikz-pgf

In plot options, I can specify the limits of the axis using `ymin` and `ymax` options.  Is there a way to specify the range, i.e., `ymax`-`ymin`, and have tikz/pgf figure out the limits?

Thanks,

Ritchie

Comment: Do you want to specify the range *instead* of or *in addition to* the `ymin`/`ymax`? And what do you mean with figure out of limits?

Comment: I want to be able to specify only the range and let latex determine the best `ymin`/`ymax`.

Comment: You are referring to `pgfplots` and its `axis` environment here, right? I don't think what you're asking is available.

Comment: Just came across this again. As I said, I don't think anything like this is built into `pgfplots` (and I honestly don't see the point, but that's another matter). Anyway, how do you define "best"? You can always make a feature request at SourceForge: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/?source=navbar